# mapping one class to two tables from different database in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, orm, sqlalchemy

I want to make a management script which read a lot from slave db, surely replicated from master, and write sometimes into master db. Tables that I'm accessing are the same. one from slave, and one from master. So I'd like to use just one mapping class for both of them. how can I map this class to two tables from different databases?

Comment: Why don't you just create two sessions, one to each database, and use the slave session when reading and master session when writing?

Comment: @JonathanOng thank you for your suggestion. I've totally misunderstood bind and session in sqlalchemy. using two session and one mapping table, what I want works perfectly. =) BTW, any good way to copy an object from one session to another? python's copy or deep copy can't do that. Even session's expunge don't, either.

Comment: i think you use session.merge() for the session you want that object to exist on

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be interested in database routing.  There is a master/slave example on this page:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/